# Package needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 16.04

I tried installing kazam screen recorder for my ubuntu 16.04 OS and then I got the following error.

E: The package libstdc++-5-dev needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: How exactly did you try to install that program? Is that the full error message?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libstdc++-5-dev), *libstdc++-5-dev* belongs to the **Ubuntu Main Repository**, so if it can't be installed it means you don't have access to such repository, which you should.

To enable Ubuntu Main Repository go to *System Settings > Software and updates > Ubuntu Software* and make sure **at least the two first items** (main and universe) are checked:

[image]

If somehow you just want to download that lib without enabling Main Repository (not recommended as you will face more problems in the future) you can get it here:

- [For Ubuntu 16.04 - 64bits](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libstdc++-5-dev_5.3.1-14ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html)
- [For Ubuntu 16.04 - 32bits](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-main-i386/libstdc++-5-dev_5.3.1-14ubuntu2_i386.deb.html)